# Why won't this method call work?

Tags: java, methods

I'm creating a method to take an input by a user and validate it to make sure it's correct.  If it's correct it will call a method and input the user input in to it.  But for some reason, the method call is not working.  It doesn't produce any errors, it just simply doesn't do it.  I placed a print statement at the end of the code to make sure it actually reaches there and it does, but for some reason it's just not calling the method like it's supposed to.  The other method works fine if I call it by itself and input a string via the parameters.

The code is:

```
public void getGetScheduledShowByFilmInput()////new - omar////
{
    BufferedReader reader;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String filmInput;
    filmInput = "";

    boolean foundFilm;
    foundFilm = false;

    System.out.println("Here is a list of films that are currently showing:");
    for(Film film : films){
        System.out.println(film.getFilmName());
    }

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Please type the film name that you wish to view the corresponding shows for and press enter.");
    System.out.println("Type 'exit' and press enter to exit this process.");

    while(foundFilm == false){
        try{
            filmInput = reader.readLine();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

        //If user enters "exit" then return.
        if(filmInput.equals("exit")){
            return;
        }

        //Check to see if the film name input by the user corresponds to any film showing.
        for(Film film : films){
            if(film.getFilmName() == filmInput){
                foundFilm = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(foundFilm = true){
            System.out.println("Film found.");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The film name you entered has not been recognised.  Please try again.");
        }
    }

    //Call the function and input the film name input by the user.
    getScheduledShowsByFilm(filmInput);  ////This is the code that seems to be the problem.
    System.out.println("reached bottom");

}
```

and the second method is:

```
 public void getScheduledShowsByFilm(String inputFilmName)
{
    ArrayList<Show> scheduledShows;
    scheduledShows = new ArrayList<Show>();
    for(Film film : films){
        if(inputFilmName == film.getFilmName()){
            for(Schedule schedule : schedules){
                scheduledShows.add(schedule.getShowsOfFilm(film));
                if(scheduledShows.get(scheduledShows.size() - 1) == null){
                    scheduledShows.remove(scheduledShows.size() - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(Show show : scheduledShows){
        System.out.println("**********************************");
        show.getShowDetails();
        System.out.println("**********************************");
    }
}
```

The second method works perfectly when I call it on its own and enter parameters manually though.

It's probably something extremely simple that I'm not understanding! haha, thank you for your help :)

Comment: How do you know it's not being called? From what I can see, you declare and initialise the BufferedReader, but you don't read anything in (unless there's more code that you haven't posted there. Also, have you tried printing a test message out in the function to see if it's reached?

Comment: Can you post `getScheduledShowsByFilm`?

Comment: Never mind @ my comment. Just noticed your edit.

Comment: Ah right haha, thank you anyway :) yeah sure two seconds :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

foundFilm can never be false because you always assign true to it:

```
 if(foundFilm = true){
            System.out.println("Film found.");
 }
```

try changing it to this:

```
if(foundFilm)
{
   System.out.println("Film found.");
}
```

Comment: While that is an issue, that doesn't explain his problem at all.  Admittedly his problem is a little vague, but it seems like he's saying that `getScheduledShowsByFilm` is not being called.

Comment: @Omar: you really wanted to do: `if (foundFilm == true)` with a double equals sign, but as Hunter shows, `if (condition == true)` is the same as the simpler `if (condition)`

Comment: That's not the problem, that part of the code works fine.  I assigned it to false at the beginning and it changed during the while loop.  it does work, the print statement I've placed at the bottom of the code prints out "reached bottom" meaning it's reached it, that part of the code is working fine.  thank you for your input though :)

Comment: @Omar: similarly, your `while (foundFilm == false)` would be traditionally written as `while (! foundFilm)`.

Comment: The while loop will only ever execute once, which probably isnt what you @OmarQassem want.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen That does seem to be the case.  I assumed that his print statement was being called like he said.  I didn't notice that the print statement at the end was the same as the one in the loop.  +1 and sorry about that.

Comment: The while loop doesn't only loop once, I've tried entering invalid data and it loops around again, printing that I've entered invalid data and asking for another input.  The while loop is working fine, honestly.  at the end I'm printing out what the user has entered too and it's the correct data, but the method call just isn't working

Comment: Actually you are correct, why is it doing that? haha, I'm very sorry.  my bad!

Comment: Well, the loop does loop, but for some reason if I enter invalid data, even if i re-enter valid data it will just show a message telling me the film is not recognised and that I need to re-enter

Answer (score 0):

In `getGetScheduledShowByFilmInput()` and `getScheduledShowsByFilm(String)` avoid doing string comparison using the equality operator (==). The == operator tests for object equality, but you want to test whether two strings contain the same sequence of characters. Therefore, use `equals` instead:

```
    //Check to see if the film name input by the user corresponds to any film showing.
    for(Film film : films){
        if(film.getFilmName().equals(filmInput)){
            foundFilm = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

and

```
for(Film film : films){
    if(inputFilmName.equals(film.getFilmName())){
        for(Schedule schedule : schedules){
            scheduledShows.add(schedule.getShowsOfFilm(film));
            if(scheduledShows.get(scheduledShows.size() - 1) == null){
                scheduledShows.remove(scheduledShows.size() - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  That sorted it all :) thank you very much.  I'm new to this site, could you please tell me how I'd go about giving you +1?

Comment: @OmarQassem Since you have already accepted Hunter's answer you cannot accept mine as well. (I must confess that I am not sure if you could change the the accepted answer as I have never asked a question on SO myself...). You can upvote my answer using the arrows to the left of the answer however. The section about how to ask ( http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask ) in the FAQ has additional details.